# Timing duration between two events

Tags: c++, time, arduino, stopwatch

I want to compute the time between when I transmit and when I receive. My timer will start counting once I start transmitting then the timer will stop once I receive a response.  I'm using `C++` on my `arduino uno`. Base on my code I'm just measuring the delay, Which is not good. what I'm trying to measure is the elapsed time between i transmit and received. I hope you can help me.

[output image](http://postimg.org/image/r3587q3wf/)

**My code**

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>         

const int transmit_pin = 12;       
const int receive_pin = 11;                  
char *controller;         

unsigned long start, finished, elapsed;         

void setup() {          

  //receiver settings         

  Serial.begin(9600);   // Debugging only         
  vw_set_rx_pin(11);         
  vw_rx_start();          

  //transmitter settings         
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);         

  vw_set_ptt_inverted(true);          
  vw_set_tx_pin(12);         
  vw_setup(1000); // speed of data transfer Kbps         

}         
void displayResult()         
{         
  float h,m,s,ms;         
  unsigned long over;         
  elapsed=finished-start;         
  h=int(elapsed/3600000);         
  over=elapsed%3600000;         
  m=int(over/60000);         
  over=over%60000;         
  s=int(over/1000);         
  ms=over%1000;         
  Serial.print("Raw elapsed time: ");         
  Serial.println(elapsed);         
  Serial.print("Elapsed time: ");         
  Serial.print(h,0);         
  Serial.print("h ");         
  Serial.print(m,0);                  
  Serial.print("m ");         
  Serial.print(s,0);         
  Serial.print("s ");         
  Serial.print(ms,0);         
  Serial.println("ms");         
  Serial.println();         
}         

void loop() {         

  //Transmitter         
  digitalWrite(13, 1);         
  controller = "1";         
  vw_send((uint8_t *)controller, strlen(controller));         
  vw_wait_tx(); //Wait until the whole message is go         

start=millis();         
delay(1000); // for debounce         
Serial.println("Started...");         

  //Receiver         
  uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];         
  uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;         

  if (vw_get_message(buf, &buflen)) { // Non-blocking          
  digitalWrite(13, 0); //Flash a light to show received good          
  for(int i = 0;i < buflen;i++) {         
  if (buf[i] == '2')          
  {         

finished=millis();         
delay(1000); // for debounce         
displayResult();         

  elapsed=finished-start;                          
  Serial.print(start);                
  Serial.println(" milliseconds start");                   
Serial.print(finished);                   
  Serial.println(" milliseconds finished");                     
    Serial.print(elapsed);                    
  Serial.println(" milliseconds elapsed");                    
  Serial.println();                   

  }           
    }              

  }                
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You say "Base on my code I'm just measuring the delay, Which is not good."

Ok, well:

```
start=millis();         
delay(1000); // for debounce
```

Well, if you don't want to include the delay in your elapsed time, then take the start time *after* the delay(), not before.

This seems to be too obvious, so I suspect that you're really asking about something else. You need to show the output you're getting, why you think it's wrong, and what output you expect to get, instead.

Comment: I did what you said sam , now im getting is zero value. I dont really know what is the problem. i hope you can help me.

[image](http://postimg.org/image/r3587q3wf/)

this is the output image when used the delay after the start time.
[image](http://postimg.org/image/wsq25rzgf/)

Comment: millis() suggests that your clock's resolution is in milliseconds. There are only a 1000 milliseconds in a second. It's entirely possible that the code that you're trying to measure takes less than a millisecond to run.

Comment: What should i do sam? should i chance the code in determining the time? what if i change millis() into micros()?

Comment: Since there are a million microseconds in on seconds, you're far more likely to get meaningful results.

Answer (score 1):

Every thing happens during your delay period (the 1000ms delay). The message is received and stored in the buffer waiting for you to read it while you're in the delay. You're now measuring the execution time of a couple of lines of code and that takes less than a millisecond that is why you are getting the 0ms time.